# AJAX is not working in macOS WebView

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a WebView for macOS app and it contains one AJAX call. The same WebView is working fine when the app calls my local URL, but when it calls the live URL, the AJAX call is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#pripolcheck').click(function () {
        var pripolcheck = $('#pripolcheck').val();
        var app = $('#app').val();
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
        var contact = $('#contact').val();

        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        var dataString = 'pripolcheck1=' + pripolcheck + '&app1=' + app + '&user_id1=' + user_id;

        if (pripolcheck == '') {
            alert('Please Fill All Fields');
        } else {
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://mywebsite.com/ajaxformsubmit.php',
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    // alert(result);
                    // $(".pripol").hide();
                    $('.pripolcheck').prop('checked', true);
                    $('input.pripolcheck').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

My local PHP version is 7.1.8 and my live server PHP version is 5.4.

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: I'm not getting any errors also,when user clicks the checkbox ajax should get called but it's not getting called

Comment: reset cache and try,

Comment: local ? Live? what is the difference? Is the page on the same server? what is the errors in the console/ajax call.

Comment: How do I reset? in my code or macapp code? I don't understand

Comment: @epascarello My localhost PHP version is 7.1.8 and my live server PHP version is 5.4

Comment: So what is the error in the console/network request?

Comment: You should add an `error` function to your ajax call along with the `success` one to get an eventual error. One thing i notice is that you have only the file name in the `URL`, maybe it's as simple as that? in local, client and server are at the same place, but not in live version, the client is your browser and needs to know the server address for the call

Comment: are you entering in the success statement ? if not add the error statement to your settings

Comment: @epascarello Not getting any error

Comment: Yes you are, you are just not showing it because you are not adding the error handler to the Ajax call.

Comment: in the network panel, the HTTP code is 200 for your ajax call ?

Comment: @Kaddath could you please give example to add error function?

Comment: there is a documentation for that http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: One more thing it's working in live link also but only not working in WebView

Comment: So did you add the error handler to the jQuery's Ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to onclick of checkbox directly,put this code in your checkbox `onclick="MyFuncion"`,why I'm telling this is for web view we need to give exact command in exact position it's not a browser

And your AJAX call will be like below,

```
function myFunction()
 {
   var pripolcheck = $("#pripolcheck").val();
   var app = $("#app").val();
   var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
   var contact = $("#contact").val();
   // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
   var dataString = 'pripolcheck1='+ pripolcheck + '&app1='+ app + '&user_id1='+ user_id;
   if(pripolcheck=='')
    {
      alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    }
  else
   {
  // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "ajaxformsubmit.php",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     success: function(result){
     // alert(result);
     // $(".pripol").hide();
     $('.pripolcheck').prop('checked', true);
     $("input.pripolcheck").attr("disabled", true);
    }
 });
 }
 return false;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"My local PHP version is 7.1.8 and my live server PHP version is 5.4."
```

I think this explains everything.

However, try setting an absolute URL in your call:

```
url: 'ajaxformsubmit.php',
```

to

```
 url: '/ajaxformsubmit.php',
```

Or whatever the actual path would be. Just a single slash will give you

`http://wherever.com/ajaxformsubmit.php`

Comment: Excuse me, but that doesn't "explain" anything, it's just a hint, no reason is exposed here, only a person knowing the answer already could see an "explaination" here :/

Comment: Live also working when I test in browser but only not working in mcaos app webview

Comment: again, try with an absolute URL rather than a relative one.

Comment: ah no, dont put the domain in, it should just be the slash if thats the full URL, so just `url: '/ajaxformsubmit.php'`

Comment: for full URL it's not working for this one it will work?

Comment: try it and see, it should still work locally etc, so leave it in if it does, and we can eliminate that possibility if still not in the webview

Answer (score -2):

if u use same site url plz use relative path not absolute path then its ok.

if use defrant site url plz comment me so give me new solution

PLZ try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#pripolcheck').click(function () {
    var pripolcheck = $('#pripolcheck').val();
    var app = $('#app').val();
    var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
    var contact = $('#contact').val();

    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    var dataString = 'pripolcheck1=' + pripolcheck + '&app1=' + app + '&user_id1=' + user_id;

    if (pripolcheck == '') {
        alert('Please Fill All Fields');
    } else {
        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ajaxformsubmit.php',
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                // alert(result);
                // $(".pripol").hide();
                $('.pripolcheck').prop('checked', true);
                $('input.pripolcheck').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

});